# Classes in Matlab and switch statement

Tags: string, matlab, class, oop, switch-statement

I'm using *OOP* concepts in *Matlab's language*, I have a class containing different cases, how can I make them efficient using *classes and objects*, so that the object of class can be called in simple *Matlab's* code. The objects or simple variables can be accessed if class is called.
How can I reduce the cases and object can assign strings with only input a number?

My code:

```
classdef myClass
        properties
           Obj1; %..... other objects
            choice;
        end
        properties (Access=private)
        num   
    end
        methods
            function obj = myClass(num)
                obj.num = num;
            end
            function Choice(obj)
               switch choice
case 1
obj.Obj1 = 'Obj1';
case 2
obj.Obj1 = 'Obj1';
obj.Obj2 = 'Obj2';
case 3
obj.Obj1 = 'Obj1';
obj.Obj2 = 'Obj2';
obj.Obj3 = 'Obj3';
%similarly 100 cases
            end
        end
         methods (Static)
        function myStaticMethod
            disp(obj1); %.... other objects
return; %objects return
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of objects instead of a separate property for each object. You can then use array indexing to add/remove objects to/from that property:

```
properties
   Objects = []
end
```

You can access the property and index into it:

```
obj.Objects(k) = ...
```

And you can use a for loop to display:

```
for k = 1:length(obj.Objects)
   disp(obj.Objects(k))
end
```

Comment: But how can I assign "obj.Obj1 = 'Obj1';" so that the class returns the assignment.

Comment: I am suggesting not to use `obj.Obj1`. If `obj.Objects` was an array, you can always return a subset of it using `obj.Objects[1:choice]`. You probably need to read a bit more about MATLAB arrays.

Comment: in properties, obj.Objects have a syntax error using '.'

Comment: Sorry I meant to define `Objects` as a property. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It can't be accessed from index file, gives error 
Undefined variable "obj" or class "obj.Objects".

Comment: And also, reurns this array after running the class,  Objects: [0 0 3]